# How to make GtkTextView look like GtkEntry?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade, gtktextview, gtkentry

Or "How to add a visible (thin) border to GtkTextView"? Is it ever possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to confuse your users like that?

Comment: @ptomato I need the same thing. It is not to confuse the user, but to not confuse the user. I want a 3-line text widget that behaves exactly like an Entry widget (but with 3 lines). The only way I could find is to modify a TextView widget...

Comment: @ptomato Users will be confused without this (even I became confused).

Answer (score 9):

Years later... but searching the web still gives no good answers to this question.

The solution is quite simple: Just create a `GtkFrame` and add the `GtkScrolledWindow` containing the `GtkTextView`, here is some example code in python:

```
frame = Gtk.Frame()
scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroll.set_hexpand( True )
scroll.set_border_width( 3 )
textview = Gtk.TextView()
scroll.add( textview )
frame.add( scroll )
```

Comment: There is no need for a GtkFrame; GtkScrolledWindow is enough.

Answer (score 2):

After about 9 and a half years later...

I'm going to give a language-independent answer.

First, add a `GtkScrolledWindow`, it'll enable scrolling. Now add your `GtkTextView`. Then set shadow type to something other than none. It'll show a border around your `GtkTextView`.

Comment: Interesting workaround. IMO it would be simpler if the GTK devs just add support for that as-is, but as a work around it is ok; I was thinking of using a gtk-frame. Good to know a scrolled-window can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Glade editor:

- In glade editor select your *ScrolledWindow* (you have packed *TextView* into *ScrolledWindow*, haven't you? :), if not - select your *TextView*).
- Select ***Widget Porperties*** -> ***Common*** tab.
- Find and adjust ***Border width*** property to your liking.

From code:

call `set_border_width(width)` method of container widget (either *ScrolledWindow* or *TextView*)

Note, that in any case *TextArea* will not exactly look like *Entry* and it depends on gtk+ theme being used.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gtk.ScrolledWindow.set_shadow_type(type=gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN)` will improve the look but won't match the style of `gtk.Entry`.

The border of the scolled window or textview is not an issue if placed in a window or pane, but if the goal is to create a form with a multi-line entry field it becomes ugly. Here is a hack that may do the trick...

```python
import gtk

# create an entry widget that we use for appearances only
e=gtk.Entry()
e.set_size_request(width=250, height=150)

# create a texview and accompaying label
lbl = gtk.Label(str="Comments: ")
lbl.set_alignment(xalign=1, yalign=0)
field = gtk.TextView(buffer=None)
field.set_wrap_mode(wrap_mode=gtk.WRAP_WORD) # or gtk.WRAP_CHAR

# we need a scroll window
sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow(hadjustment=None, vadjustment=None)
sw.set_border_width(border_width=4)
sw.set_size_request(width=250, height=150)
sw.set_policy(hscrollbar_policy=gtk.POLICY_NEVER, vscrollbar_policy=gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
sw.add(field)

# create more widgets as needed for form here...
lbl2 = gtk.Label(str="email: ")
lbl2.set_alignment(xalign=1, yalign=0)
field2 = gtk.Entry()

# put everything in a table so the fields and labels are all aligned 
tbl = gtk.Table(rows=1, columns=2, homogeneous=False)
tbl.attach(lbl, left_attach=0, right_attach=1, top_attach=0, bottom_attach=1, xoptions=gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK, yoptions=gtk.FILL, xpadding=0, ypadding=0)
# sw and e must be attached in this order, the reverse will not work
tbl.attach(sw, left_attach=1, right_attach=2, top_attach=0, bottom_attach=1, xoptions=gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK, yoptions=gtk.FILL, xpadding=0, ypadding=0)
tbl.attach(e, left_attach=1, right_attach=2, top_attach=0, bottom_attach=1, xoptions=gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK, yoptions=gtk.FILL, xpadding=0, ypadding=0)
# comment out previous line to see difference

# attach other widgets here...
tbl.attach(lbl2, left_attach=0, right_attach=1, top_attach=1, bottom_attach=2, xoptions=gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK, yoptions=gtk.FILL, xpadding=0, ypadding=0)
tbl.attach(field2, left_attach=1, right_attach=2, top_attach=1, bottom_attach=2, xoptions=gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK, yoptions=gtk.FILL, xpadding=0, ypadding=0)

# display it!
window = gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(350, 200)
window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
window.add(tbl)
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

The caveat is that the scrollbar(s) becomes invisible; it can be selected, and scrolling works as usual. This may be a minor issue if the data to be entered in the field tends to not make use of scrolling.